# If statements, logical AND, comparisons

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm new to MIPS assembly language. Just started to learn. I've got this problem where I have to display a letter grade for the test score that the user inputs. I've done this so far, but I cannot get it to work. I always keep getting invalid or sometimes the program ends or gives a D.

It is assumed:

```
Score Range Letter Grade 
90 to 100 A 
80 to 89 B 
70 to 79 C 
60 to 69 D 
0 to 59 F
```

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and correct my code!

```
.data

prompt: .asciiz "Enter a test score [0 to 100] or -1 to stop: "
invalidPrompt:  .asciiz "Invalid \n"
A:  .asciiz "A \n"
B:  .asciiz "B \n"
C:  .asciiz "C \n"
D:  .asciiz "D \n"
F:  .asciiz "F \n"

.globl main
.text

main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    #move $a1, $v0

    beq $v0, -1, end    # -1 to stop

checkA:              
    bge $v0, 90, checkB
    ble $v0, 100, checkB
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, A
    syscall
#    j main

checkB:       
    bge $v0, 80, checkC
    ble $v0, 89, checkC
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, B
    syscall 
 #   j main

checkC:    
    bge $v0, 70, checkD
    ble $v0, 79, checkD 
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, C
    syscall 
#    j main

checkD:    
    bge $v0, 60, checkF
    ble $v0, 69, checkF 
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, D
    syscall 
#    j main  

checkF:    
    #bge $v0, 0, invalid
    ble $v0, 59, end
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, D
    syscall 
#    j main

invalid:    
    blt $v0, 0, end
    bge $v0, 100, end
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, invalidPrompt
    syscall
#    j main                                          
j main

end:

#--- TERMINATE ---
      li $v0, 10       # terminate program run and
      syscall          # return control to the OS.
```

The second part of the problem is I have to display the number of A's, B's and so on after user enters -1. How can I go about this? I know I have to store the count of each grade when true in a separate register and keep incrementing but not sure how this is done.

Edit: I am using MARS 4.1 tool on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1:

```
checkA:              
bge $v0, 90, checkB
ble $v0, 100, checkB
```

Here you test if $v0 is between 90 and 100, and then jump to checkB. You must check if it is not between 90 and 100:

```
checkA:              
ble $v0, 90, checkB
bge $v0, 100, checkB
```

Part 2: Just initialize $t1 to $t5 to zero, and increment $t1 when A, $t2 when B, ...

Comment: so if both are false then it goes to next one right? but then where do I print the letter grade?

Comment: If both are false, then you print the letter. After the printing, jump to the end of all the tests.

Comment: Also if the user enters 75 for example, how do I output like "75 is C" ?

Comment: thanks, but I have to keep looping until the user inputs -1, so where do I put this loop?

Comment: Just after both tests. If they fail, they will execute the code after it (thus if not smaller than 90 and not greater than 100, execute). The whole loop should be placed around the whole program (j main, essentially), so after printing, just jump.

Answer (score 1):

You have your logic backwards.
GE = GREATER THAN OR EQUAL
LE = LESS THAN OR EQUAL

Also you don't really need the logical AND operator at all if you start with the smallest and work your way up.

- IF grade == -1 THEN EndProgram
- IF grade < 0 THEN Error
- IF grade < 60 THEN F
- IF grade < 70 THEN D
- IF grade < 80 THEN C
- IF grade < 90 THEN B
- IF grade < 100 THEN A
- ; grade must be greater than 100 so
  Error

> ```
> main:
>     li $v0, 4
>     la $a0, prompt
>     syscall
>
>     li $v0, 5
>     syscall
>     #move $a1, $v0
>
>     beq $v0, -1, end    # -1 to stop
>
>     ble $v0, 0, invalid 
>
> checkF:
>     bge $v0, 60, checkD
>     li $v0, 4
>     la $a0, F
>     syscall
>     j main
> checkD:
>     bge $v0, 70, checkC
>     li $v0, 4
>     la $a0, D
>     syscall
>     j main
> checkC:
>     bge $v0, 80, checkB
>     li $v0, 4
>     la $a0, C
>     syscall
>     j main
> checkB:
>     bge $v0, 90, checkA
>     li $v0, 4
>     la $a0, B
>     syscall
>     j main
> checkA:
>     bge $v0, 101, invalid
>     li $v0, 4
>     la $a0, A
>     syscall
>     j main
> invalid:    
>     li $v0, 4
>     la $a0, invalidPrompt
>     syscall
>
>     j main
>
> end:
>
>       li $v0, 10       # terminate program run and
>       syscall          # return control to the OS.
> ```

Comment: thanks, why didn't I think of that! Can you share the syntax of how this is done? Also to loop the program until the user inputs -1, is using "j main" the right way?

Comment: @HelloWorld - There are many correct ways to solve the problem. But getting a basic understanding of logic and of how the MIPs instructions work should be your first priority.

Comment: Ah yes, I see where I went wrong. I was following the book's method of translating if statement and I messed up the logic. It goes to the next line only if the branch statement is false and executes that.

Comment: Another question I have is how can I do this: if the user enters 75 for example, how do I output like "75 is C" ? How can I get the value in the output? In Java and C this is so simple, but in assembly?